# Golang вывести значения в html

Tags: html, golang, шаблоны

Есть button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default"></button>
```

Передаю модель с данными в html

```
func TakeToRepairTreatment(rnd render.Render){
  bks := models.ModelTakeToRepairTreatment()
  rnd.HTML(200, "take_to_repair_treatment", bks)
}
```

В **bks**  есть поле Lgotcat, как его подставить в

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Сюда</button>
```

Таблицу заполняю без проблем:

```
        {{ range $key, $value := . }}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <form action="edit" method="POST" >
                    <button type="text" class="btn btn-default btn-md">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$value.Id}}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>{{$value.Id}}</td>
            <td>{{$value.DateRecord}}</td>
            <td>{{$value.Fam}} {{$value.Name}} {{$value.Lastname}}</td>
            <td>{{$value.Datebirth}}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="print_queue" method="POST">
                    <button type="text" class="btn btn-default btn-md">
                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$value.Id}}">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                </form>
            </td>

{{end}}
```

А как вывести значения одного поля, не в цикле, не могу разобраться.

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если bks - это структура с полем, то просто

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">{{.Lgotcat}}</button>
```

Comment: проблема в том, что bks это "массив" и нельзя обратиться к полю простым .Lgotcat

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев Тогда что вам мешает так же вывести в цикле? `{{$value.Lgotcat}}`? Или что вы хотите, я не пойму.

Comment: Тогда в цикле выведется все записи с льготными категориями (которые еще и в таблицу загружаются) мне нужно вывести одну запись нечто вроде .Lgotcat[1]

Comment: @ЕвгенийГусев Тогда почему вы не используете [функцию `index`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Functions)?